# Trying to share a folder with host and guest in Virt - manager / KVM

Tags: samba, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I am trying to share a folder in Virt - manager in Linux host using Samba to my Windows 10 guest. I have tried connecting via ip "\10.0.2.2" as recommended in an outdated guide about virtualizing Windows XP. Am I using the wrong ip, or is there an up to date guide on folder sharing? Is samba the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your IP with

```
ip addr
```

You will need to add the directories you want to share in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` directory.

I'm not sure how you're planning on sharing your drives with guest or user auth. But the [samba wiki](http://wiki.samba.org) might be a good place to start.